Para el resultado de un algoritmo, ChatGPT, Gemini y Copilot dicen una cosa, Claude dice otra
El código es muy fácil, es el siguiente:
int k = 1;
    k += (k = 4) * (k + 2);
    System.out.println("Result: " + k);

El resultado segun ChatGPT, Gemini AI y Microsoft Copilot, es 28, cuando le pregunto a Claude, el resultado da 25...
Incluso si yo mismo lo compilo, a mí el resultado me da 25...
Hasta me corrigen, adjunto:

k se inicializa en 1.
Se asigna 4 a k.
Se calcula (k + 2) como 6.
Se multiplica 4 por 6, obteniendo 24.
El error está en la última parte:
No se suma 24 al valor original de k (que era 1).
Se suma 24 al valor actual de k después de la asignación, que ya es 4.
Por lo tanto, la operación final es: k = 4 + 24 = 28.
El resultado correcto es 28, no 25.

No comprendo. ¿Se equivocaron 3 IA en un código tan sencillo?

¿Se equivocaron 3 IA en un código tan sencillo? La respuesta ya la tienes: "Incluso si yo mismo lo compilo, a mi el resultado me da 25...". Como empecemos a dudar de los resultados experimentales porque una IA trata de concencernos de que son imposibles... Son IAs alucinando, nada nuevo por aquí... Si lo piensas, el resultado no es tan raro si tienes en cuenta que  k += ((k = 4) * (k + 2));   equivale a  k = k + (((k = 4) * (k + 2)));, es decir k = 1 + 4 * 6

Por qué insistes tanto en los resultados de las IA?? Son programas para analizar texto... no ejecutan código. Y por encima, "alucinan". Es tan fácil como preguntarles How many "R"s in "Strawberry" (cuantas R hay en "stRawbeRRy") y ver que te responden que hay dos, y te lo defienden. No son perfectas, ni muchísimo menos... sin embargo la gente piensa que lo que dice la IA es decreto del Señor mismo... y va a ser que no :) Como te han dicho, tú mismo has ejecutado el código... acaso dudas que tu instalación de Java haya hecho una ejecución correcta???

es por el orden de precedencia del operador de asignación y la evaluación de la asignación en la sintaxis del lenguaje. k += "algo" se expande a k = valor de k (actual) + "algo".  cuando se evalúa el "algo", k no vuelve a ser evaluado. diferente sería si la expresion fuera k = (k = 4) * (k + 2) + k;

la razon por las que la ia se equibocan es porque son "modelos de lenguajes" no matematicos, en el caso de claude lo que hace para solventar este problema, es crear scripts ejecutarlos y tomar el resultado... nada interesante pero muy util para evitar este problema... pero desde la filosofia de openai/google esto es hacer trampa dado que rompe el esquema para lo que fue diseñado en todo caso este no es un sitio para preguntar porque una ia se equiboca....

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Este comportamiento está documentado, ver el ejemplo 15.7.1-2, donde se muestra claramente que el comportamiento de Java es que la reasignación de la variable sucede después de la evaluación
Tu expresión:
k += (k = 4) * (k + 2);

Es lo mismo que
k = k + (k = 4) * (k + 2);

Lo que quiere decir que el primer k + .... se evalúa antes que k = 4, y es el comportamiento esperado, por lo que tu ejercicio es:
k = 1 + 4 * (4 + 2) = 25


Una operación binaria está compuesta de 2 operandos y un operador, tal que a + b

a operando izquierdo
b operando derecho
+ operador

Y aquí lo importante !!!: Java siempre evalúa primero el operando izquierdo y luego el derecho
Veamos un ejemplo, digamos que tenemos las siguientes funciones
int A()
{
    System.out.println("A");
    return 2;
}
int B()
{
    System.out.println("B");
    return 3;
}
int C()
{
    System.out.println"C");
    return 4;
}

Y luego:
int k = A() + B() * C();
System.out.println("Result: " + k); //14
// imprime:
// A
// B
// C
// Result: 14

Esto te muestra que, aunque la multiplicación se realice primero, las evaluaciones de las funciones se realizan de izquierda a derecha. Si siguiera el orden de precedencia debería imprimir (B,C,A) pero no es el caso
Volvamos a tu ejercicio, tu expresión consta de varias operaciones. Es posible agruparlas de tal manera que nos quede una única operación binaria. Digamos que:
A = (k = 4)
B = (k + 2)
C = A * B

Nota: Observar que no es posibles hacerlo de otra manera, por ejemplo agrupar C = k + A sería aritméticamente incorrecto
Entonces tenemos que:
k = k + C

Y ahora paso a paso:
// Primero se evalúa el operando izquierdo, k se convierte en 1
k = 1 + C
   // Luego el derecho, hay que evaluar internamente
   C = A * B
   // primero el izquierdo
      A = (k = 4) // A es 4 y desde aquí en adelante `k` es 4, porque esto recién ocurre en este momento
   C = 4 * B
   // Luego el derecho
      B = (k + 2) // B es 4 + 2 es decir 6
   C= 4 * 6 // 24
K = 1 + 24 // 25


